# Good book on history of mechanics

Tags: physics, book-recommendation

For absolute beginners in  physics, what are some good books in the history of physics (especially mechanics) ? (But it should not be full of mathematical hand waving - actual historical development wth mathematical background should be there)

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/352110/2451

Answer (score 5):

*A History of Mechanics*, by René Dugas, is a classic.

Comment: Nice book. It's worth pointing out that there is also a [Dover Publications edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486656322), and [here's a review of the book](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/133/3463/1472.1).